# Python and ftdi FT2232H spi full duplex

Tags: python, ftdi

I am trying to set up a communication between computer and FTDI FT2232H using python to control spi protocol in full-duplex mode. The libraies I tried such as "pyftdi", "pylibftdi" have spi protocol, but it is in half-duplex mode. Full-duplex means that the computer can send and receive data simultaneously. Can you give me some advices?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Some advice: first check the device you are communicating with supports `full-duplex` mode. If you use `SPI MPSSE` library (`libMPSSE_spi`), there is a function `SPI_ReadWrite()`. See [this link](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI.htm) for more information.